# Trying to have a Broadcast Receiver with No filter

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("test");
registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
```

I would like to have no filter like `registerReceiver(mReceiver, null)` but my app crashes as a result of that. Can I have `new IntentFiler()` as an empty filer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the BroadcastReceiver returns `null` when there is no match via the criteria from the `IntentFilter`, it is not possible with the API to accomplish what you hope to accomplish (which I'm assuming is sending any and all Broadcasts to `mReceiver`).

You can certainly specify an empty `IntentFilter`, but this will be pretty useless as registering the receiver won't cause it to catch any broadcasts (unless they are directly targeted to the receiver, as mentioned by MisterSquonk in the comments).  Otherwise you must know exactly which broadcasts you want to catch with your BroadcastReceiver, then specify the criteria in the IntentFilter.

Comment: "...registering the receiver won't cause it to catch any broadcasts." - Are you sure? It's possible to register a `BroadcastReceiver` using a `<receiver>` element in the manifest which has no `<intent-filter>` element. In this case you send an `Intent` to that receiver by explicitly specifying its class as you would directly target an `Activity`. Example, `Intent i = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);`

Comment: @MisterSquonk, true, thanks for bringing that up.  I was thinking in terms of non-directional broadcasts.  I'll update my post.

Comment: yeah, I guess we should not be that lazy, also was trying to send Intent without any String set