# Does a Android BroadcastReceiver need to have an Intent-Filter tag?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I have been able to get my BroadcastReceiver running with this:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
</receiver>
```

As you can see no `<intent-filter>`. It gets called correctly with the right `Intent` extras. But I have been looking around and I am confused as to whether I need one or not? I do have a `setAction()` method called on my `Intent`s but to make them unique from others to ensure a specific issue with notifications, not actually using that action's string. But what exactly is the correlation? Thanks in advance.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.getContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction("com.something"+System.currentTimeMillis());
        //... extras are here
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getContext(), 123, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT|Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getContext().getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

Using that with what I have in the manifest file works.

**EDIT**
I found this on the Android Developers blog, and it states this:

---

**Implicit Intents** only specify “what” they should match, using actions, categories, data, 
MIME types, and so on. The exact components that they will find are only determined at 
run-time, by the Package Manager matching it against the current applications.

**Explicit Intents** specify a single explicit “who” they should match, through a 
ComponentName. Regardless of whatever else is in the Intent, it is only associated with 
the exact manifest package name and class name as given in its ComponentName.

---

I am still slightly confused with this explanation, but it seems to be the closest thing to what I should be doing. So I am sure I am using an implicit intent. Question is, is it ok that I am leaving out `<intent-filter>`? I am matching it to a specific class. There may not be an actual action tying them together, perse, but is the class enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<intent-filter>` is required when you want to start your receiver using implicit intents, if you are always using explicit intents to start your broadcast receiver then intent-filters are not required.

see [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060137/android-broadcastreceiver-with-no-intent-filter).

Comment: Thanks a lot for that link. I know the guy well on here, so I will ask him directly.

Answer (score -1):

The entire way a broadcast receiver works is it involves using an Intent Filter to catch specific broadcast intents that are sent within the system. So if you give the receiver no intent filter, then NOTHING will be sent to it and its code will never execute.

Please read the documentation of Intent and learn how Intent allows IPC.

**Update**

Also its possible that without any declarations it could be receiving  all public broadcasts and the way your code handles it.. is it ignores all the broadcasts except the ones it cares about. I've never done that this kind of implementation because I follow the standard. Which is to declare either as a dynamic listener (Programatic) or a static listener (XML declaration), where the dynamic listener would have its Intent Filter set in code.

Comment: Thats really weird because mine is working just fine. Like I said, my `BroadcastReceiver` gets all the intent extras correctly. But I have the above in my Manifest file. Sooo, I would normally take more experienced peoples word for it, but in this case, it seems this is not true. Any ideas why?

Comment: You should just follow the standard as set by Google, which is what I said, if you look at their source code, this idea is utilized many times. Don't really need to question it, all it is.. is IPC.

Comment: Also its possible that without any declarations it could be receiving  all public broadcasts and the way your code handles it.. is it ignores all the broadcasts except the ones it cares about. Which leads to that code executing more than it needs to.

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting, and I much appreciate the advice. I do have one problem. I need to set the `setAction()` in that specific way, if not then there is a problem I get with setting notifications. This means the action needs to be unique...

Comment: You need to update your post with your specific problem details.

Comment: I just realized another thing. How could I be receiving public Broadcasts when I have `android:exported` set to false. This essentially says that I cannot be receiving anything from outside my own Application.