# Prevent a service from starting at startup

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

My broadcast receiver runs automatically when app starts.

How to prevent this? I want to start it on button click.

BroadCastReceiver:

```
public class TestAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @DebugLog
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, TestService.class);
        i.putExtra("foo", "bar");
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

IntentService:

```
public class TestService extends IntentService {

    public TestService() {
        super("TestService");
    }

    @DebugLog
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Service is running");
    }
}
```

Also, I added these lines to AndroidManifest file inside application section:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".service.TestAlarmReceiver"
        android:process=":remote" />

    <service
        android:name=".service.TestService"
        android:exported="false" />
```

Comment: Here are some useful links [android:enabled](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html) and [android-broadcastreceiver-with-no-intent-filte](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060137/android-broadcastreceiver-with-no-intent-filter). To start from button click you could use Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestAlarmReceiver.class);
sendBroadcast(intent);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set `android:enabled="false"` ([options for receiver](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html#enabled)) for your receiver on your manifest and then activate it using [package Manager](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/manifest-receivers.html) to enable it.
Then you could write this function on the button click:

```
public void enableReceiver(Context context) {
    ComponentName component = new ComponentName(context, TestAlarmReceiver .class);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                component,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

To stop the Receiver at runtime you only have to use the constant `PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED` instead of `PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED`.

I can't try it right now, but this should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, now works like a charm. I start it a little bit different, because I need AlarmManager for periodic tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I used quite rough method, but it works for me!
In class extends BroadcastReceiver

```
if (MyService.getInstance()==null) return;
```

Where in service.

```
private static MyService ins;
public static MyService getInstance() {
    return ins;
}
```